# "InterlockedExchange" for strings

Tags: c++, mutex

I need an equivalent to InterlockedExchange, which I can use for assigning a string to string.
This equivalent should be usable in c++. I know that I can start implementing my own mutex-based solution, but was wondering if there's anything ready and elegant.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible on commonly used hardware. I think you'll need a lock.

Comment: Hi david, I agree. By "equivalent" I meant something as short and elegant without actually having to start implementing the locking system myself.

Comment: @user OK, the thing you are looking for is a lock/mutex

Comment: I suspect you may be abusing InterlockedExchange, and writing thread-unsafe programs.

Comment: @John: why do you say that? *wanting* to atomically swap arbitrary variables is pretty natural. It's a shame it can't be done in hardware, but if it was supported, it'd be a natural way to solve a lot of threading problems. Simply asking about it just means that the OP wishes to try for the simple and intuitive solutions first, before digging in and writing all the painful threading code manually.

Comment: @jalf Using a mutex is hardly painful. Code with locks is generally much easier than lock-free.

Comment: @David: you're missing the point. If there was a way to just atomically swap arbitrary variables, that would be *the easiest* way to swap variables in a thread-safe manner. Since you don't know exactly what the OP is trying to do, it's silly to pretend that it'd be simpler with a mutex than if he could just do this operation directly. And using a mutex can get painful when you start getting deadlocks. ;)

Comment: @jalf No, I don't think I am missing the point. Compare and swap operations are not performed because you are interested in exchanging two items, they are performed because they enable lock-free synchronisation. The exchange operation is never the ultimate goal, it just facilitates something more complex. What's more, compare and swap is typically used to update a simple value. The analog for a string is to update the string. This is utterly trivial with a mutex. There will be no deadlock because only a single lock is needed.

Comment: @David: He is not asking about *compare and swap*, but *exchange*.

Comment: And true, using a single mutex is trivial, but in my experience, you tend to have more than one in a multithreaded application. And then it becomes less trivial. There's a reason why so much effort is being expended on finding better ways to parallelize code

Comment: @jalf You are right, it's not CAS. Point taken. Why would you need multiple locks to implement InterlockedExchange?

Comment: @David: no, not multiple locks to implement a swap, but multiple locks in an application which *uses* a swap. (most likely, the to-be-swapped data is accessed by other parts of the code as well) Anyway, my point is simply that if all you need is a thread-safe swap, then I don't blame you for wishing the CPU supported thread-safe swaps of arbitrary variable types. A mutex is just a clumsy workaround for that.

Comment: @jalf OK, I see where you are coming from. Multiple locks are only a problem when you take a lock whilst already holding another one and that would not be the case here.

Comment: @David: but again, we don't know that. We don't know how many locks are in his application, which ones he's already holding, and so on. Without context it's hard  to justify the *knee-jerk* reaction that "you shouldn't consider other options, a mutex is the simplest way to do thread synchronization"

Comment: @jalf On the one hand you are saying, just assume that all the OP wants is to exchange two values. On the other hand you are saying, we know nothing of what the OP is doing, so we can't assume anything. Anyway, I don't think we are adding anything to human knowledge with this discussion!!  ;-)

Comment: I was merely looking for something like CreateMutex..WaitForSingleObject...ReleaseMutex..CloseHandle.

WinApi.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid not.  The whole point of `InterlockedExchange` is that it (atomically) works on a single 32-bit or 64-bit (With the 64-bit version) value.  Strings involve memory allocation, copying of memory and bounds checking, so this cannot be achieved this way.

The closest you'd get, I reckon, is by exchanging two string pointers so they point to something different (that is already allocated).  But even then, how do you know the contents of that string is not being written to?

Answer (score 1):

If you can store pointers to your strings you could do an interlocked exchange of the pointers. You're going to need a lock of some kind to swap actual strings though.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a non-mutable reference-counted string class, it is easy enough to implement with boost::shared_array as the underlying type or even boost::shared_ptr< const std::string >. (I will often have a fixed-size buffer for short strings when doing this).

The "interlocked exchange" could then be used in the increment of the reference-count of the shared_ptr when you assign. Actually, boost::shared_ptr already supports this so you don't have to write anything yourself.

When I say the string class is non-mutable I mean you cannot directly modify the string in it. You can however extract a copy of the std::string, modify that, then attach a new actual string to the class.

Comment: Not convinced that this is a very wise approach.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct hardware support for this.

However, it would be trivial to do using Software Transactional Memory (it'll have to be a software implementation, since hardware support is still pretty experimental)

With STM, you can do arbitrary memory operations atomically, and let the library worry about ensuring thread safety.